# Overlay image over animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animate, media9, movie15

Is there any way to overlay an image over an animation (like in webpages) in beamer using either

```
ainmategraphics,\begin{animateinline},\movie or \includegraphics
```

together with

```
tikzpicture
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more precise what you're trying to do?

Comment: I wish to make a titlepage, where, one side of the page shows an animation, while the other side should contain the title, author etc.. overlaid as an image over the animation.  I will share below an example gif image to get a feel of what i mean. [See Example Image  Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9f3x461iatwd1e/test3.gif?dl=0)

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) how you include your animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any plugin-based animation (`multimedia`, `media9`, `movie15`) plays in a separate layer on top of the page content and cannot be overlaid by typeset material or embedded graphics or images, irrespective of the order of occurrence in the document source file. It always bubbles up to the top layer (foreground) when activated.

`animate`-generated animations *can* play in the background of other material if the OCG method is used (package or command/environment option `method=ocg`). However, achievable frame rates may become lower as compared to the standard `icon` animation method, in particular when combining complex animations and rich page content, because the complete page has to be re-rendered with every animation frame refresh.

Example ([**↗ShareLaTeX**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/592fb9c82178ae9a17739813)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}

\begin{document}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,width=3cm,loop,method=ocg]{2}\multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{\strut\i}\end{animateinline}}
\rotatebox{60}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\Huge\color{red}Hello World}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szgrwxj3ni3btdq/SESol.pdf?dl=0) is what i got by compiling using Lualatex

Comment: Fine! I get the same.

Comment: :( So its impossible :(

Comment: What is impossible? The example overlays "Hello World" on top of an animation. This is what you requested.

Comment: Remove `method=ocg` and see the difference. Of course, a JavaScript-enabled PDF viewer, such as Acrobat Reader, is required.

Comment: I am getting the animation overlaid on the text when i remove `method=ocg`
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axygd9i8uehht3x/SESol1.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: I am getting all the frames bundled as one whe using `method=ocg`
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jq3km905tdvwolo/SE.png?dl=0). There is no animation happening. I tried using adobe acrobat for linux

Comment: @Vishnu You are using an old, possibly bugged version of animate.  I inserted a link to ShareLaTeX in my answer.

Comment: Yep. It works :)